# Office 365 permission list of a single user in different collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, office-365, reports

I want to see all various site permissions which user has in all site collections - globally within my organization. Office 365.

My idea is a Powershell script which would make a report about all/specific user’s permissions on SharePoint sites, subsites, lists etc., dumped do csv.

There are hundreds of sites so I know the script would have to go by batches. I don't know how to search for a specific person, so I would search for a whole site permissions and then filter out csv.

At this point it looks pretty complicated and I have a basic idea of Powershell posibilities. So I need your opinion how to manage such a big topic and how to bite the script over different sites? 
Recently I found information only about execution in site collection.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online: Permission Report for Specific User in a Site Collection using PowerShell for your reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/09/sharepoint-online-get-user-permission-report-using-powershell.html